# Using SecureString with LogonUser

Tags: c#, .net, security, securestring

For learning purposes I am writing my own Active Directory client. In order to execute commands like unlocking accounts and resetting passwords, I have to put in my admin account and password and use and `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate` run the code as my admin account. I am wondering about my options for securing my password, as it has to be used many times across my program.

From what I understand, I can use `SecureString` to store the password. But to run code as  my admin account, I have use `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`, and to use that I have to get a token from `LogonUser` which requires a regular `string` and not `SecureString`.

So I would have to:

1. Login at start up
2. Convert input to a `SecureString`
3. Clear the input

Then later when I want to preform a function that requires elevation:

1. Convert previously created `SecureString` to `string`
2. Pass the converted string to `LogonUser`
3. Clear the convert string to `null`
4. Execute command
5. Clear the `LogonUser` object

Is this the correct way to approach this? It seems weird to have to have to convert the `SecureString` to `string` to use it... seems like it would defeat the purpose and leave the password more vulnerable while I am converting it.

EDIT: Fixed the name for LogonUser

Comment: You're right that converting to string defeats the purpose. What is UserImpersonation? Does it PInvoke to a Win32 API? You may have to change the function it uses to pass in IntPtr instead of string.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry... I'll fix my question. Yeah, `UserImpersonation` is a class I wrote a loooong time ago... it's basically a wrapper for [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , which also requests a string for a password. Can that be changed to an `IntPtr` ? If that's the case, could I just pass a `SecureString` to the password parameter instead? (I'd try now but I am no longer at work...)

Comment: No you can't use `SecureString` directly but it should not be difficult to pass in the password safely. I will answer below...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `UserImpersonation` class, change how you declare `LogonUser` to use `IntPtr` instead of `string` for password.

The code sample for [Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.securestringtoglobalallocunicode(v=vs.110).aspx) has exactly what you need. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern bool LogonUser(String username, String domain,
                                      IntPtr password, int logonType,
                                      int logonProvider, ref IntPtr token);

...

IntPtr tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

IntPtr passwordPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{
    // Marshal the SecureString to unmanaged memory.
    passwordPtr = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);

    returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, passwordPtr,
                            LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle);

 }
 finally
 {
     // Zero-out and free the unmanaged string reference.
     Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(passwordPtr);

     // Close the token handle.
     CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
 }
```

Comment: @duckwizzle No worries